# AWS Recommended POD sizes in Kubernetes - EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am new to EKS and looking for the number of pods per node and sizes of EC2 instances for nodes, recommended by AWS in EKS for better performance and HA? 
I found limitations set by Kubernetes.io in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cluster-large/). But I want to know what AWS's schools of thoughts when we run our clusters with EKS?   You may share your experience too.

This is not for polling, but to know the standard usages.

Comment: I'd say: that completely depends on your workload..

Comment: @RickyA . Thanks. But can I know what is the usual way ?

Comment: The typical approach @DhanushkaN is to get your applications deployed into your cluster and run something like `kubectl top nodes`. This will let you know how much of your cluster CPU you're using vs your cluster RAM. These two metrics will let you know the type of instance you need (c5.large vs m5.large for example). It's also recommended to favour larger instances since they have a much higher limit of IP addresses that can be assigned to them.

Answer (score 8):

There is a hard limit to the number of pods that can be run on a particular worker instance type.  This is because, by default, Amazon's VPC CNI assigns a subnet IP to each pod.  [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI) page lists how many interfaces/ips per interface a particular instance type can have.  One interface is reserved for the host, so you get your answer by ( Maximum Network Interfaces ) * ( IPv4/6 Addresses per Interface ) - 1.  For example, with a t2.medium, you get 17 pods.

Picking the right type, as mentioned by RickyA, is an exercise you will have to go through.